# Laravel 6 one --> many relationship in resource controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I currently have an application that can have a modifier with many options. An example use case is a modifier of Toppings with options of cheese, lettuce, salt, and pepper. A modifier can have 1 --> N options.

I want to have a form that displays the `Modifier` name and also allows the ability to edit/delete `Option` records at same time. I want to embed this in my current form for adding/editing modifiers.

Is there a simple way to do this so I can have just one Modifier resource controller that also manages Options?

web.php

```
Route::resource('modifiers', 'ModifierController')->middleware('auth');
```

Controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Modifier;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ModifierController extends Controller
{

    public function create()
    {
            $data = ['action' => route('modifiers.store'),'method' => 'POST', 'modifier' => new Modifier()];
      return view('modifiers.form',$data);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
            $modifier = new Modifier($request->all());
            $this->do_validate($request);
            $modifier->save();
            return redirect(route('modifiers.index'));
    }           
}
```

views/modifiers/form.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.layout-2')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">

            @include ('layouts.errors')

        <div class="col-md-12">

                    {!! Form::open(['url' => $action, 'method' => 'post', 'class' => 'form', 'id' => 'form'])!!}                                    
                    @csrf
                    @method($method)

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">{{ __('modifiers.name')}}</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value = "{{old('name',$modifier->name)}}">
                     </div>



                  <button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('common.submit') }}</button>

                    {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Models:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Modifier extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];    

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Option');
    }       
}

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Option extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function modifier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Modifier');
    }

}
```

Comment: This options can be displayed with a `select` element?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a `select` element:

```html
<select name="options[]" id="options" class="form-control">
    @foreach($options as $option)
        <option value="{{ $option->id }}" {{ $modifier->options->contains('id', $option->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $option->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Hope it helps.

Then, within some controller:

```php
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $modifier = Modifier::find($id);
    $modifier->options()->sync($request->input('options'));

    // Do whatever more you want to do

}
```

Comment: I didn't put this in question, but each Option can have a `name` and a `selling_price`. I need to be able to add, edit, and delete these options when modifying a Modifier. Is there a clean way? Note that this needs to work on new modifiers and existing modifiers

Comment: With your question i was thinking that you only need to select the options and attach it to the modifier. So, if you want to modify the `option`, you can't use select. I think a good option is to use something like a form, with input fields to the option name and selling_price. When you modify the option value, use ajax to send it to your backend.